# Netbeans-esque retrospective auto-comment/phpDocumentor tool (for Eclipse or standalone)

Tags: php, netbeans, netbeans-plugins, phpdoc

Is there anything similar to netbean's Javadoc auto comment tool for PHP/phpDocumentor/Eclipse? [In the netbeans implementation:](http://edu.netbeans.org/quicktour/javadoc.html)

> A dialog pops up and allows you to run
>   through all the members of your class
>   and enter comments, which are added to
>   the source file. It even verifies that
>   there are no parameters you have not
>   accounted for, so you can be sure that
>   your comments are complete.

Ideally this would be standalone software, but plugins are OK too :)

p.s. netbeans 6+ [auto comment was moved/renamed](http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=5306181). Now in "Tool->Options", Tab: "Java Code", Javadoc: "Hints"

**edit**: screengrab of the original Netbeans tool:
[image]
<sub>(source: [vsj.co.uk](http://www.vsj.co.uk/pix/articleimages/dec03/netbeans8large.jpg))</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Also if you use vim, you'd be doing yourself a great disservice to not look at Tobias Schlitt's [VIP toolset](http://schlitt.info/opensource/blog/0719_pdv_vip_now_on_github.html) (VIP = VIM integration for PHP).

Answer (score 0):

Not quite automatic, but close. [Here](http://blogs.oracle.com/netbeansphp/entry/generating_php_documentation_from_netbeans) is how to generate phpDocs from your PHP code

Comment: I can generate phpDocs just fine, it's creating the comments by stepping through existing code that I'm after :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if eclipse has an auto documenting feature or not, but you might check out http://www.zend.com/community/pdt.  Eclipse is basically like netbeans, but it is very easy to obtain plugins for a multitude of other languages.  The link I gave should give you eclipse with the php part included.

Comment: I use PDT and it does not have the retrospective auto-doc functionality that Netbeans used to offer. Do you know of a similar plugin?